# Client side validations undefined method `validates_email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I copied the code from client_side_validations page. And i had error 
`undefined method validates_email for #<Class:0x007ff3382428a8>`
When i put `includes ::Validations` in my model this error disappeares but validation doesn't work at all.

app/validators/email_validator.rb

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
    record.errors.add(attr_name, :email, options.merge(:value => value))
    end
  end
end

# This allows us to assign the validator in the model
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
  def validates_email(*attr_names)
    validates_with EmailValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
  end
end
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      email: "Not an email address"
```

app/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.customValidators.js

```
// The validator variable is a JSON Object
// The selector variable is a jQuery Object
window.ClientSideValidations.validators.local['email'] = function(element, options) {
// Your validator code goes in here
if (!/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test(element.val())) {
// When the value fails to pass validation you need to return the error message.
// It can be derived from validator.message
return options.message;
}
}
```

models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :email, :ip, :name, :post_id
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :content, :email, :post_id, :name
  validates_email :email
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you including your module. Also, depending on where you put your module, you will sometimes need to "require" it. And also, try:

```
include <Module name>
```

instead of

```
includes <Module name>
```

hope this will help